# ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage issue while uploading app to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am encountering an issue while trying to upload my iOS app to App Store Connect. The Xcode organizer displays the following error message:

```
ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public selectors in Frameworks/AmazonChimeSDKMedia.framework/AmazonChimeSDKMedia: terminate. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at ...
```

**Context:**

I am using the "AmazonChimeSDKMedia" framework in my app, and it appears that there are references to non-public selectors within this framework, which is causing the rejection during the app review process.

**What I've Tried:**

Reviewed the changelog of the "AmazonChimeSDKMedia" framework to check for updates or fixes related to non-public API usage, but no specific mention was found.

Checked my app's codebase and third-party libraries for direct references to non-public selectors but could not find any.

Ensured that I am using the latest version of the "AmazonChimeSDKMedia" framework available.

**Next Steps:**

I'm not sure what specific non-public API references are causing the issue. I need assistance in identifying and resolving these references so that I can successfully upload my app to App Store Connect without encountering the "ITMS-90338" error.

**Question:**

How can I identify the non-public API references within the "AmazonChimeSDKMedia" framework that are causing the rejection?

What steps should I take to resolve this issue and make my app compliant with Apple's guidelines?

I appreciate any guidance or insights from the community. Thank you!